# Select в Angular

Tags: angular2, angular, angular5

Всем привет. Недавно начал работать с angular и у меня возникла задача. 
Есть Select который содержит 2 options: Dark mode и Day mode. Как сделать что бы при выборе Dark mode в body добавлялся атрибут "themedark"?

Comment: вы серьезно? добавьте обработчик `change` и используйте `setAttribute`

Comment: Спасибо. Я так и сделал изначально, только проблема в том что при переходе на другие страницы выбранное значение селекта сбрасывается. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: кешировать и сохранять в localstorage/redux сторе

Comment: Можно таскать с собой из $rootScope